# why does grid(row=) stop at 3? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

im making a to-do list and i made a add button it only works the first time and after it stays in the same spot

i tried making two variables 1 for the rows for the to do thingys and one for the add button and each time you add one both of them get incremented by 1

i was expecting each time the add button will go down by one row but intead it went diwn once and then stayed there

```
import tkinter as tk  

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("160x270")

var1 = 0
var2 = 1

def add_new_check():
    global var1, var2
    tk.Entry().grid(row=var1, column=1)
    tk.Checkbutton().grid(row=var1, column=0)
    var1 += 1
    var2 += 1

add_new_check()

tk.Button(root, font=('Arial', 10), text="+", command=add_new_check).grid(row=var2, columnspan = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `grid` call for the button uses the value of `var2` at the time of the call. If you want to update the position, you have to store the `Button` object and call `grid` on it again with a new row value.

Comment: it would be simpler to use `pack()` to put `Frame` and `Button` and later in `Frame` use `grid()` to add new `Entry` and `Checkbutton`. This way new element in `grid()`  (inside `Frame`) will automatically move `Button` in `pack()`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `tk.Checkbutton().grid(row=var1, column=0)`, it puts the widget at the row defined by `var1`. It doesn't (and can't!) remember that it was based on a variable and update itself when the variable changes. That's simply not how it works.

If you want to change the row at a later date, you must call `grid` again with the new row value.

Answer (score 0):

It will not change position of `Button` when you change value of `var2`

It would be simpler to use `Frame` to keep elements `Entry` and `Checkbutton` in `grid()` and keep `Button` outside `Frame`/`grid`.

You can use `pack` to put `Frame` and `Button`, and later use `Entry(frame)` and `Checkbutton(frame)` to put elements inside `Frame`

This way you don't have to move `Button` because it will move it automatically (because it is outside `grid`)

```
import tkinter as tk  

# --- functions ---

def add_new_check():
    global var1
    tk.Entry(frame).grid(row=var1, column=1)
    tk.Checkbutton(frame).grid(row=var1, column=0)
    var1 += 1

# --- main ---

var1 = 0

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry("160x270")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="+", command=add_new_check)
button.pack()

add_new_check()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

**By the way:**

If you want to access `Entry` and `Checkbutton` then you may need to keep them on list, or you need to use `StringVar`, `BooleanVar`, `IntVar` in `Entry` and `CheckButton` to have access to values. You have keep them also on list (ie. `items`)

If you don't plan to remove items from `grid` then you can use `var1 = len(items)` to add new element in `grid()`

```
import tkinter as tk  

# --- functions ---

def add_new_check():
    #global var1
    
    var1 = len(items)
    
    var_entry = tk.StringVar(root)
    tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=var_entry).grid(row=var1, column=1)
    
    var_check = tk.BooleanVar(root)
    tk.Checkbutton(frame, variable=var_check).grid(row=var1, column=0)
    
    items.append( (var_entry, var_check) )
    
    #var1 += 1

def save():
    """TODO: save in file."""
    for entry, check in items:
        print('entry:', entry.get())
        print('check:', check.get())
        print('---')

# --- main ---

var1 = 0

items = [] # list for pairs [entry. check]

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry("160x270")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button_add = tk.Button(root, text="+", command=add_new_check)
button_add.pack()
#button_add.pack(fill='both')   # resize button

button_save = tk.Button(root, text="SAVE", command=save)
button_save.pack()
#button_save.pack(fill='both')   # resize button

add_new_check()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! #this is for the 15 char min limit

Comment: I add example which uses `StringVar` and `BooleanVar` to have access to values in grid.